# When to use #define vs typedef?

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

So,I'm trying to cut down on `using namespace std` all the time,since I now somewhat understand what conflicts it can cause in the code,and even though I'm not gonna be using someone else's code anytime soon,I want to train myself on using good practices...

But I still don't like the way the code looks when you sprinkle scope operators all over it,one advice I came across is to use `typedefs` to customize how things looks a bit,what I wrote was:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

typedef std::cout std_cout;
typedef std::endl std_endl;
typedef std::string std_string;
typedef std::fstream std_fstream;
typedef std::ios std_ios;
```

Now when I type this everything is fine,except for the first two lines(in the second block of code),which give me the `variable "std::cout" is not a type name` and `function template "std::endl" is not a type name` error messages respectively.

Now if I were to replace all `typedef`s with `#define`s,the problem would initially appear to have been solved,but then I'd end up with numerous syntax errors in each line that contains one of these definitions. (Besides I know that `#define` is also equally as problematic as `using namespace std` so I'm trying to avoid that one as well)

To complicate matters even further,the first line (in the same block),which is the one of the two problematic lines here,is one straight up identical to one that I have seen in numerous sources online,so I don't know what's right anymore...

How do I define data type correctly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? Just use `std::cout` so other C++ programmers can read your code. Inventing your own dialect helps nobody and achieves nothing. The `std::` prefix is there for a reason, both as a way of separating the `std` namespace from your code, but so people can look up documentation without having to puzzle through what something weird like `std_cout` actually is.

Comment: Hint: `typedef` is for types and `std::cout` is not a type. You could define a global variable, like `auto& std_cout = std::cout` but that's going down a road that should not be gone down.

Comment: one option would be to get used to seeing `std::`

Comment: As the name suggests, `typedef` defines types. It's not for making pre-processor macros or aliases. That's what `#define` is for. Also, what the hell, are you coding in C++ or are you trying to come up with your own language?

Comment: In this case, neither a typedef not a macro is needed (and, for `cout` and `endl` a `typedef` is wrong, since they're not types).   All that is needed is a using declaration `using std::cout` or (if you don't want to write a series of declarations) a using directive, such as `using namespace std`.    No matter how you do it, that comes with tradeoffs (e.g. if there are other namespaces with the same names).    Practically, it's often better to get used to reading and typing `std::` and fully qualifying the names/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, `std::cout` is not a type, it's an object. Hence, use of

```
typedef std::cout std_cout;
```

is not going to work.

Use of

```
typedef std::string std_string;
```

is legal. However, I have the following concerns.

1. When a reader of code sees `std_string`, they will wonder what it means and will have to track down its definition. That's an unnecessary waste of time compared to using `std::string`.
2. Use of `std_string` saves you only one character when typing. It's not much of a saving in the time it takes to create code.
3. You won't be able to stop others in your team from using `std::string`. When both exist in the code base, it's terrible.

> But I still don't like the way the code looks when you sprinkle scope operators all over it, one advice I came across is to use `typedef`s to customize how things looks a bit

That's poor advice, IMHO.

**My suggestion:** Don't bother with the `typedef`s. Just use the fully qualified name. It makes for more readable and maintainable code.